# Declare query for login

Tags: vb.net, parameters, oledb

```
Function Authenticate(ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As String)
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection(connectionstring)

    Dim cmdstring As String
    cmdstring = "SELECT username, password  FROM tblUsers where username = @user AND password = @pass"

    con.Open()

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(cmdstring, con)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = UserName
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Password

    Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If (sdr.HasRows) Then
        Authenticate = True
    Else
        Authenticate = False
    End If
    sdr.Close()
    con.Close()
    con = Nothing
    Return Authenticate
End Function
```

Can anybody help, not sure why I'm getting `A scalar variable '@user' needs to be declared` as soon as I hit this line:

```
Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: I don't think it's related to your problem, but you can do parameters like this: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", UserName)` - it'll work out the appropriate OLEDB type from the type of `UserName` for you.

Comment: what version of msAccess you're using? because theres no error here  http://www.screenr.com/gx07 this is strange :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as follows

```
cmdstring = "SELECT username, password  FROM tblUsers where username = ? AND password = ?"

con.Open()

Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(cmdstring, con)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", UserName)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", Password)
```

For some reason, the ? in the queries does the trick, also the addwithvalues adds the values in the respected ? in the query, took me a while to find this, so i thought that i would share :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the value, and not the type, and use the function like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", UserName)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", PassWord)
```

This will solve your error. Here you have more info:
[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx).

Comment: OP is said that "declared as soon as i hit this line: `Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()`" he got the error. :)

Comment: @spajce I know, and? Why the downvote? My answer is the solution!

Comment: @spajce And? I already know that. The OP gets an error on the `ExecuteReader`, but the problem is not there. Read the question again.

Comment: should i to explain? about the ExecuteReader vs ExecuteNonQuery?, the OP want a single output. okay? :)

Comment: @spajce ?¿ The OP is not asking for that. Is asking about an error he is getting, and my answer solves that. In fact, your answer not. Please remove the downvote. =/

Comment: i will try to test, if i prove that i was wrong about that, i will remove the  downvote, relax :)

Comment: this is strange bro, because i tested his code and everything fine. im using the `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\test.accdb` :D

Comment: but don't forget that the `ExecuteNonQuery` is the correct to use when the time we want a single output

Answer (score -1):

After the string
Dim cmdstring As String
    cmdstring = "SELECT username, password  FROM tblUsers where username = @user AND password = @pass"

cmdstring cmdstring.replace("@user","'" & UserName & "'").replace("pPassWord","'" & PassWord& "'")

that will create the proper query

Answer (score -2):

try to change the `.ExecuteReader()` to `ExecuteNonQuery()`

```
Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

here's a good explanation about [ExecuteReader, ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteScalar ... When to use What?](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2007/05/01/3049.aspx)

Comment: and please explain your side, why'd you downvote my answer :)

Comment: this 2 man gave a downvote for this answer, no idea what is downvotes :D, com`n guys, prove to me what should be the proper way to use this `.ExecuteReader()` to `ExecuteNonQuery()`?